# How to use firebase-tools from NodeJS script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I want to delete a Firestore collection and its sub-collections from a NodeJS script (not from a Cloud Function). I cannot get it right with project selection.

To be clear, I want to perform the same as this CLI command, but from a script:

```
firebase -P my-project firestore:delete fruits --recursive
```

Here is my attempt:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("path_to_my_service_account_key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: `https://my-project.firebaseio.com`,
});

const firebaseTools = require("firebase-tools");

firebaseTools.use("my-project");

async function deleteCollection(collectionName) {
    const ref = admin.firestore().collection(collectionName);
    const res = await firebaseTools.firestore.delete(ref);
    console.log("delete success:", res);
}

deleteCollection("fruits");
```

It throws "TypeError: Cannot create property 'project' on string 'easypinger-test'" on the firebaseTools.use line.
If I remove it, its throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined" from the delete command.
How can I make it right?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea to call `firebaseTools.use()`.  Perhaps you want to start with the code in the documentation. Note that `delete()` takes two arguments.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Comment: Thank you! It works when passing the project info as parameter to ```delete```. I was looking for a way to specify the project on which to apply my commands, I got the wrong idea to call ```use``` by reading the commands here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#admin-commands

Comment: If you post your link as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: If you wish to remove a whole database under emulation, it's good to know that there's a special emulator API for that. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/rules-unit-testing/src/api/index.ts#L616-L636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on deleting collections with firebase-tools](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) provides a template to work with.  If you want to specify a project, note that `delete()` takes two parameters.  For example:

```
firebase_tools.firestore
    .delete(path, {
        project: YOUR-PROJECT-ID-HERE,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The example given on the [firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections#cloud_function) works if you're running within a firebase function.

If you are not using firebase functions, you don't have to rely on the `firebase-functions` package to in order to get retrieve a valid token `functions.config().fb.token`.

For example you could use the `firebase-admin` package instead.

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  // APP OPTIONS
});

const cred = admin.app().options.credential;
if (!cred) {
  throw new Error('Admin credential was undefined');
}
const access_token = (await cred.getAccessToken()).access_token;

await firebase_tools.firestore
  .delete(path, {
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    recursive: true,
    yes: true,
    token: access_token
  });
```